# How to access the Schema.ObjectId to get the objects json on the client using the mean stack?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angularjs, mean-stack

My Schema looks like:

**super.js:**

```
var superSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
  },
  item: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Item'
  }]
});
```

**item.js:**

```
var itemSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
  }
});
```

My json then looks like this:

```
[{
    "title": "Team 1",
    "items": [
      "52c23f2129sdf1720d000006",
      "52c23f2129asd1720d000006",
      "52c23f212992cfdsd00000f6"]
},{
    "title": "Team 2",
    "items": [
      "52c23f2129sdf1720d000006",
      "52c23f2129asd1720d000006",
      "52c23f212992cfdsd00000f6"]
}]
```

Then I try and access the `item[0].name` in my list.html file like this `{{item[0].name}}` but it doesn't return anything and item[0] returns the id.

How can I access item[0].name in my angular html file?

My **superDuperController.js**:

```
$scope.find = function() {
    SuperDuper.query(function(superDuper) {
        $scope.superDuper = superDuper;
    });
};
```

Comment: have you try: `superSchema.find({}).populate('item').exec(callback)`

Comment: I have not.  How would I put that call in my list.html?

Comment: how do you get the json from your database?

Comment: I updated the question with my find function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to populate your items before sending the response to the client side.

```
Super.find({_id: super_id}).populate('item').exec(function(err, super) {
    if(err) {

    }
    else {
    // Populated the items
    // Send the **super** in response
    }

})
```

Now you can access `{{item[0].name}}` in your client side.

Comment: Do I do this before or after I do my find?

Comment: You should do it when you do your find.

Comment: can you update your question with the function from which you are returning the response?

Comment: I'm not sure what function you mean... I did update the question with my find function.  Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: You would be having a function in mongoose controller where you are asking super from Mongodb. Can you show me?

Comment: I figured it out using populate.  Thanks for your help Jayram